# Discord.js v12 How could I check if a message in a certain channel is a VIDEO attachment?

Tags: javascript, video, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make the bot in a certain channel if a video attachment is sent in for example `#video` and if it is actually a video attachment, the bot will reply in that channel something and copy the video attachment to another channel. If it's a text message, the bot will just delete the text message.
I currently have no code because I have no idea lol.Ž

Current code:

```
const {MessageAttachment, Client} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {

    if (msg.channel.id == '728664668834627705') { // Valiate a channel

        const attachments = (msg.attachments).array(); // Get list of attachments
        const attachment = attachments[0]; // Take the first attachment

        if (msg.content) return msg.delete() // Delet the message if it has conetnt

        if (attachments.length !== 0) {
            const nameArray = attachment.name.split('.'); //Split the name 
            const attEx = nameArray[nameArray.length - 1] //Grap the last value of the array.
            if (attEx == "mp4" || attEx == "Or what ever fromat you want") {
                // Note this doesn't check the file it check the format of the file.

                const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`728664692012089366`) // Get the channel you want to send to by id

                const snetAttachment = new MessageAttachment(attachment.proxyURL);
                return channel.send(snetAttachment)

            }
        }
        msg.delete() // Delete teh message fi it doesn't pass the validations
    }
})
```

I get an error: DiscordAPIError: Request entity too large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```js
const {MessageAttachment, Client} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();


client.on('message', msg => {

    if (msg.channel.id == '728558310340427838') { // Valiate a channel

        const attachments = (msg.attachments).array(); // Get list of attachments
        const attachment = attachments[0]; // Take the first attachment

        if (msg.content) return msg.delete() // Delet the message if it has conetnt

        if (attachments.length !== 0) {
            const nameArray = attachment.name.split('.'); //Split the name 
            const attEx = nameArray[nameArray.length - 1] //Grap the last value of the array.
            if (attEx == "mp4" || attEx == "Or what ever fromat you want") {
                // Note this doesn't check the file it check the format of the file.

                const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`728558358013018152`) // Get the channel you want to send to by id


                const snetAttachment = new MessageAttachment(attachment.proxyURL);  // Send as attachment

                
                return channel.send(snetAttachment);

            }
        }


        msg.delete() // Delete teh message fi it doesn't pass the validations
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it's perfect, when the bot reposts the clips, the video doesn't want to play, it says 0:00 / 0:00. Thats the embed. If I click on the link, it works fine.

Comment: @modricfx I have edited the answer now it is should be working

Comment: Hey, now I am getting an error `DiscordAPIError: Request entity too large`
I've put my new code on the original post.

Comment: So there's no way to increase the allowed size? It's about 20mb